# Freezing Network Stack

Tags: browser, network-programming, stack, webbrowser-control

I want to send out page requests from a browser window as fast as possible to test website responsiveness but don't have any idea how to do it.

On the receiving end is a server that will be getting multiple packets but in order to insure that they are being processed in an FIFO manner I want to send them as close to one another as possible.

The input needs to come from a web browser (doesn't matter which type or if its emulated some how) and cannot be done from the command line. My idea is to somehow freeze the network stack and then unfreezing it to release the packets all at once, but in correct order.  Is there any way to do this or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: So you are really asking about timing how long it takes to fully load a webpage?  http://blog.chromium.org/2010/07/do-you-know-how-slow-your-web-page-is.html

Comment: No I'm asking about testing a FIFO stack to make sure even if data arrives 1ms apart the server will process the first piece of data then the next.  In other words if I the command sent to the server is Insert "billy" into 'names', and the next command is select * from 'names' the result will include billy because that command came first.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP communication usually uses TCP/IP connections so the order of packets should be guaranteed. I suggest building a small web browser using `c#` with [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) and have it constantly request the website in a loop. Or, I believe this shouldn't be hard to do with other script languages like `python`.